# Non-quadratic search for specific difference between elements in sorted array

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, search

New to computer science and am attempting to verify if there are any non-quadratic approaches (i.e. better performance than Big-O of n^2) for finding a potential specific difference between either adjacent or nonadjacent elements in a sorted array of integers?

For example, if you have an array that's already been sorted, like so:

```
[1, 4, 6, 6, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16]
```

And you want to find if there's a difference between any of these elements that equals `3`, the pairs here would be `4, 1` and `15, 12` and `13, 10`.

But is there an algorithmic approach that would allow me to find these pairs without using two for loops?

Comment: I know of two.  (1) Sort the numbers, then walk 2 pointers from opposite ends towards each other, moving the left pointer rightward whenever the sum of the pointed-to elements is too small, and the right pointer leftward whenever it is too large; the invariant here is that any satisfying pair must be taken from the interval of elements spanned by the 2 pointers.  (2) Build a hash table containing every element as key (the value for each key is unimportant), then loop through every element $x$ again, checking whether $x+d$ or $x-d$ is in the hashtable.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Why not write an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I know of two.

1. Sort the numbers, then walk 2 pointers from opposite ends towards each other, moving the left pointer rightward whenever the difference of the pointed-to elements is too small, and the right pointer leftward whenever it is too large; the invariant here is that any satisfying pair must be taken from the interval of elements spanned by the 2 pointers.
2. Build a hash table containing every element as key (the value for each key is unimportant), then loop through every element $x$
   again, checking whether $x+d$ or $x−d$ is in the hashtable.

Comment: Thank you for the two suggestions, much appreciated. Regarding method 1, how would we wind up with the pair ```4, 1``` in the array ```[1, 4, 6, 6, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16]``` ?

Comment: You're welcome.  I just realised that (1) gives an algorithm for finding a pair that *sum* to a given value -- I've now edited, sorry for the confusion.  In your example, each of the differences 16-1, 15-1, 13-1, ..., 6-1 are too large, causing the pointer that started at the right-hand end to move left each time, until it stops at the 4, giving the difference 4-1 = 3.

Comment: thanks again. Just so I’m clear, in order to find all pairs with a difference of 3 using this method, you’d have to keep iterating over the array so it’s Big-O of n^2 right?

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is sorted, you can use two pointers technique. Set both of them on first element $v_1$. First pointer called $i_1$ indicates smaller item, second pointer called $i_2$ indicates bigger one. When $v_{i_2} - v_{i_1}$ is bigger or equal than required difference, move pointer $i_1$ forward, otherwise move pointer $i_2$. Since each pointer traverses each item exactly once, this is effectively linear solution.